# install vagrant ( homestead 2.0 ) without virtualization enabled

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

my computers does not have virtualization technology. I assume this could be the reason for the failure when I tried to install vagrant ( homestead 2.0 ) on top of windows.

My question is - is this Operating system dependant or Machine dependant ?

Can I install Ubuntu on one of my hard drives and install vagrant ( homestead 2.0 ) on top of Ubuntu - even if Virtualization is not supported ?

Comment: It is machine dependent. But check your BIOS before giving up, virtualization is usually disabled there by default.

Comment: I did check with http://www.intel.com/support/processors/tools/piu/sb/CS-014921.htm to know if virtualization is there or not. It is not in the hardware :(

Comment: @JavierRivera So, that sums up that, I cannot install homestead 2.0 on my machine, right ?

Comment: No. It means that you can't install homestead in your machine with good performance and without some tweaking to the virtual machine. You should be able to disable hardware acceleration for this machine using VirtualBox and it will run in your machine (albeit slow) unless it's a 64 bit virtual machine and your home machine is 32 bits.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also using vagrant on one of my computer that doesn't support hardware level visualization. So, In that PC, I'm not able to run any 64bit guest OS. I only able to use 32bit OS as guest. I believe the case will be the same for you here. Please have a look on it.

If you're interested on setting up a development environment (LAMP) on a new ubuntu machine, then please read my guide ['A developer guide to setting up Ubuntu for web development'](http://jasnan.github.io/developers-guide-to-setting-up-ubutnu-for-web-development/). In that I've described how to setup a LAMP and MEAN stacks on virtual environments in ubuntu using vagrant. May be you could use it to get a homestead running environment.

Comment: @Janson I guess, I would have a look at it. Thanks for sharing the info.